# java.awt.Image from File

Tags: java, image, file-io

How do you load a `java.awt.Image` object from a file, and know when it has loaded?

Comment: The Java Tutorial has a [page on exactly this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)and a [nice simple example](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/LoadImageApp.java).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use a [java.awt.MediaTracker](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/MediaTracker.html).

Here's a [full example](http://www.charlesli.org/java/articles/imageio/imageionotes.html).

Basically,

```
 toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
 tracker = new MediaTracker(this);
 Image image = toolkit.getImage("mandel.gif");
 tracker.addImage(image, 0);
 tracker.waitForAll();
```

Answer (score 59):

The [`ImageIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html) helper class offers methods to read and write images from/to files and streams.

To read an image from a file, you can use [`ImageIO.read(File)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#read-java.io.File-) (which returns a [`BufferedImage`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html)).
But since `BufferedImage` is a subclass of `Image`, you can do:

```
try {
    File pathToFile = new File("image.png");
    Image image = ImageIO.read(pathToFile);
} catch (IOException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use an [`ImageIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html).
So doing, you don't have to bother about any checked exceptions. Also note that it uses a `MediaTracker` when loading images from file resources.

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("image.png");
Image image = icon.getImage();
```